# Access bookmarks bar with keyboard shortcuts a la Safari

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, safari, bookmarks

Pretty much the only reason I still choose to use Safari over Google Chrome is the ability to access your bookmarks with keyboard shortcuts. For the first 9 bookmarks in your bookmarks bar, you're able to do <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the first, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the second, etc. I've looked around the chrome store and [the one I found](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omgmmhpgegfcifjmhpenmjpignkegpal) doesn't seem to work - it installs, but nothing happens when you use the keyboard shortcuts.

Do you know of any other solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any additional keyboard shortcuts defined that would override `Ctrl-0` etc. like *System Preferences » Exposé & Spaces » Spaces*?

Comment: @slhck He wants to have it in Chrome.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yeah, and if `Ctrl-0` consumes switching to another space, the Chrome extension won't be able to use the shortcut.

Comment: That's what I suspected at first, but it does not work even with disabling Mission Control shortcuts (^1 and ^2). I've looking through Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and didn't see anything that would interfere.

Comment: It works for me. But try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epljiamjefebpckdcbjelbbmepgancpg. Tell me if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension works for me only if the address bar isn't focused in Chrome.

Additionally, I had to perform some manual tweaking of system shortcuts.

It seems that these keyboard shortcuts are also assigned by default to virtual desktops that don't exist at the time of you pressing the shortcut.

So you need to first add a ton of additional desktops to Mission Control, then unassign their <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Number</kbd> shortcuts, and then (optionally) remove those desktops from Mission Control again.

This is what I did, and starting then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> worked for me.

[image: Making Ctrl-1 to Ctrl-6 work in Chrome]

Comment: I've tried that, and it still isn't working.

Comment: @EricW. Are you actually pressing `Control` and not `Command`? The extension can only do the former. When you press the shortcut, do you hear the warning sound indicating an unassigned keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It seems to be working now - the extension also doesn't work on some pages (such as the new tab page), but it's working for normal loaded webpages. That's a bummer, though - 90% of the time I want to use it is in a new tab... oh well, thanks for the help.

Comment: @EricW. See the first sentence of my answer. It doesn't work if the address bar is focused, as well. It only seems to work on actual web pages.

Comment: Even without the address bar focused, it doesn't work on the new tab page (and other chrome-internal pages such as chrome://chrome/extensions, etc) but it does work on normal pages.